# How do I write on gravestones?

Tags: terraria

With the latest 1.2 update, it appears that I can no longer write on tombstones. Normally I would do this:

1. Kill yourself.
2. Upon respawning, use a hammer to harvest the tombstone
3. Place it in another location.
4. Right click it, and a blank menu comes up with the option to edit or close it.
5. Click edit, write some text, and close it.

However, things appear to be a bit different now:

1. Kill yourself.
2. Upon respawning, use a pickaxe to harvest the tombstone.
3. Place it in another location.
4. Right click it, however there is no option to edit it.

Is there some kind of tool that will allow me to edit text on tombstones? As a side note, this tombstone was different than the ones everyone is used to; it looked more like a cross with a circle around it.

Comment: A [celtic cross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celtic_Cross)?

Comment: Yeah, I believe so. The edges were flared out a bit too.

Comment: I don't know if some just don't have it but I have seen more then my fair share of new tombstones and I was able to write on all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After attempting steps to reproduce again, they appear to now work. Either it was a bug that was fixed in one of the couple minor patches that have been released since then, or there was an issue specific to my computer that resolved itself. Either way, the issue is no longer.